# Werid behavior - Java regex expression taken from DB

Tags: java, regex

I have regex expression stored in DB - `'\\\\E\\\\'`, I use java to fetch it and match it to Strings.

I thought that since java reads from the DB it knows to escape SQL special characters by itself, and all I need is to escape the regex special chracters, so this expression actually matches `'\\E\\'`.

Problem is that it macthes `'\E\'` rather then `'\\E\\'` , why?

Comment: I had to make an extra escape while posting this question.... :)

Comment: Better highlight the regex in the editor and press Ctrl-K to turn on code formatting.

Comment: @TimPietzcker that made a huge mess! I had to undo the extra escaping...

Comment: Which is precisely the problem illustrated by your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a regex to match one literal backslash character, you need to use four backslashes in a Java string.

- The regex `\\` matches one literal backslash.
- The string `"\\"` denotes a single backslash.
- Therefore, in order to build a regex that consists of two backslashes, you need a Java string with four backslashes.

So you need `"\\\\\\\\E\\\\\\\\"` to construct a regex that matches `\\E\\`...

Comment: SHouldn't it be 8 ?? -- > *in order to build a regex that consists of two backslashes, you need a Java string with four backslashes.*

Comment: @TheLostMind: No. A string with four backslashes builds a regex that consists of two backslashes which matches one literal backslash. This is what I wrote in my explanation. If you want to match *n* backslashes, of course you need *n*x2 backslashes in your string.

Comment: @TimPietzcker But I don't palce value into string like this `String rx = "////E////"`, I get it from ResultSet, so why would it build regex with half of the backslashes?

Comment: I guess I got confused :). I thought you were saying you need 4 backslashes to match 2 backslash literals :P

Comment: @TimPietzcker I accept your answer, But I would like to understand the reason behind it. why the double tap? why would the string that is not contructed by developer (e.g. gotten from DB) will reduce special characters again?

Comment: @Alaychem: How did the string get into the DB?

Comment: @TimPietzcker In this case, manually. (Mysql workbench), I've confirmed that `////E////` is what the DB holds.

Comment: Then it seems someone entered the regex into the database instead of the string needed to "encode" the regex...